# Vagrant synced_folder NFS permissions problems on Linux

Tags: linux, vagrant, nfs

I'm very tired of trying and read about the correct config for Vagrant synced_folder with NFS on CentOS 7 as guest and Elementary OS Luna as host, I can't do to work nginx with a shared folder.

My config is this:

Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.5"
config.vm.synced_folder "/opt/lampp/htdocs", "/usr/share/nginx/html",
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "nginx",
    mount_options: ["dmode=755,fmode=644"]
```

I tried too

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/opt/lampp/htdocs", "/usr/share/nginx/html",
    owner: "nginx",
    group: "nginx",
    mount_options: ["dmode=755,fmode=644"]
```

And

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/opt/lampp/htdocs", "/usr/share/nginx/html",
    :nfs => true
```

And the command ls in the guest machine

```
drwxrwxr-x. 1 vagrant nginx  4096 ene  1 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx   nginx    17 ene  1 17:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant nginx   537 sep 16 09:56 50x.html
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant nginx   537 sep 16 09:56 index.html
drwxrwxr-x. 1 vagrant nginx  4096 ene  1 22:13 test
```

I've also changed the nginx user name to vagrant. In each change I've been us vagrant reload command.

Inside of /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2015/01/01 22:25:01 [error] 1009#0: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.5"
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, after a few days I solve it with rsync:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/usr/share/nginx/html", **type: "rsync"**
```

http://ryansechrest.com/2014/04/unable-set-permissions-within-shared-folder-using-vagrant-virtualbox/